# Get specified content between two lines

Tags: linux, sed

I have a file t.txt of the form:

```
abc 0
file content1
file content2
abc 1
file content3
file content4
abc 2
file content5
file content6
```

Now I want to retain all the content between abc 1 and abc 2 i.e. I want to retain:

```
file content3
file content4
```

For this I am using sed:

```
sed -e "/abc\s4/, /abc\s5/ p" t.txt > j.txt
```

But when I do so I get j.txt to be a copy of t.txt. I dont know where I am making the mistake..can someone please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `sed`:

```
$ sed -n '/abc 1/,/abc 2/{/abc 1/d; /abc 2/d; p}' file
file content3
file content4
```

#### Explanation

- `/abc 1/,/abc 2/` selectr range of lines from the one containing `abc 1` to the one containing `abc 2`. It could also be `/^abc 1$/` to match the full string.
- `p` prints the lines. So for example `sed -n '/file/p' file` will print all the lines containing the string `file`.
- `d` deletes the lines.

`'/abc 1/,/abc 2/p'` alone would print the `abc 1` and `abc 2` lines:

```
$ sed -n '/abc 1/,/abc 2/p' file
abc 1
file content3
file content4
abc 2
```

So you have to explicitly delete them with `{/abc 1/d; /abc 2/d;}` and then print the rest with `p`.

---

With `awk`:

```
$ awk '$0=="abc 2" {f=0} f; $0=="abc 1" {f=1}' file
file content3
file content4
```

It triggers the flag `f` whenever `abc 1` is found and untriggers it when `abc 2` is found. `f` alone will be true and hence print the lines.

Comment: thanks a lot...can u please explain what would {} and semicolon and -ne mean :). I know n stands for suppressing printing...but the rest seem new to me..can u please help a bit..so that i dont commit the same mistake again

Comment: Now I see `-e` is not necessary, so `-n` does what you say: supress printing. Updating with more explanation.